# pip list cmd shows tensorflow installed but cant import it

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have created a virtual environment with python 3.6 and installed various packages using pip, when i do `pip install tensorflow` it says "Requirement already satisfied". However when i import it, I get No module name tensorflow.python

Comment: can you add statement of how you import ? 
did you use any virtual envirionment ? do you use multiple versions of python ?

Comment: yes I have python 3.7 as well as 3.6 installed on my machine with 3.7 as default. In virtual environment i am using 3.6 and for importing tensorflow, for now i'm just testing in cmd prompt as "import tensorflow".

Answer (score 0):

And as every guy should know the very first solution of every problem...
Uninstall and reinstall
Yep, It worked.